# I cant find Leauge of Legends on the playonlinux "testing" box

Tags: playonlinux

I cannot find the "league of legends" game under the "testing" category that all the online tutorials tell you to do.

I have installed play on Linux through:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Have I done anything wrong?

(( play on Linux version 4.0.14 ))

Comment: Have you looked through every category?

Answer (score 0):

It might be temporarily hidden, try installing it from it's profile page or copy its installer's source code into local file and run it manually ( *Tools > Run Local Script* ):

https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html

Unfortunately I don't know any easy way to just download a script from PlayOnLinux page... it leaves us with Copy & Paste.